Unexpected problem while integrating the Weierstrass $\wp$ function
I would like to calculate some integrals in terms of the Weierstrass $\wp$ function. My code is as follows.
Tau = I/2;
a = 2/3; 
Inv = WeierstrassInvariants[{1/2, Tau/2}];
P[z_] := WeierstrassP[z, Inv];
PPrime[z_] := WeierstrassPPrime[z, Inv];
Z[z_] := WeierstrassZeta[z, Inv];

b[j_, z_] := Piecewise[{
    {P[z]^(j/2), EvenQ[j] == True},
    {-(1/2) P[z]^((j - 3)/2)*PPrime[z], EvenQ[j] == False && j > 1}
    }, Z[z] - Z[z - a] - Z[a]];
W[z_] = P[z - 1/3]^2;

m[i_?NumericQ, j_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
   Re[b[i, Tau/2 + t]]*Re[b[j, Tau/2 + t]]*
    Re[W[Tau/2 + t]], {t, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100];

Therefore we are calculating the integral
$$
m[i,j] = \int_{0}^1 b_i \left( \frac{\tau}{2} + t \right) b_j \left( \frac{\tau}{2} + t \right) W \left(\frac{\tau}{2} + t \right) \, \text{d} t
$$
Functions $b_i$ and $W$ are real-valued on the contour of integration (from general theory of elliptic functions), and that`s why there is a Re on the code.
In this code we have two different parameters, Tau and $a$, for $Tau = I$ and any choice of $a \in (0,1)$, mathematica can calculate the integrals. For any other value of Tau, Mathematica returns the the error message.
The integrand
Re[WeierstrassP[(-(1/3)+I/4)+t,WeierstrassInvariants[{1/2,I/4}]]^2] \
Re[WeierstrassP[I/4+t,WeierstrassInvariants[{1/2,I/4}]]] \
Re[-WeierstrassZeta[2/3,WeierstrassInvariants[{1/2,I/4}]]-\
WeierstrassZeta[(-(2/3)+I/4)+t,WeierstrassInvariants[{1/2,I/4}]]+\
WeierstrassZeta[I/4+t,WeierstrassInvariants[{1/2,I/4}]]] has \
evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the \
region with boundaries {{0,1}} 

Above was for $m[1,2]$, but I get the same for every other choice $m[i,j]$.
Am I missing something? I thought that by putting the _?NumericQ on the code this sort of error would be resolved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For unknown reasons, WeierstrassInvariants and WeierstrassP with accurate arguments due not evaluate to numbers with precision of 100.
However, if you convert the integrand to precision of 100 it will work:
m[i_?NumericQ, j_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Re[b[i, Tau/2 + t]]*Re[b[j, Tau/2 + t]]*Re[W[Tau/2 + t]] // 
    N[#, 100] &, {t, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100];

m[1, 2]

6881.66192614924470712644475278472171910449441942212404090115338427070\
2608016223896106944747819598386

